# PyQGIS: using changeAttributeValues on new feature

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I try to write a Python script with PyQGIS to update automatically a field when a feature is added or when a geometry is changed. It's work well with the `geometryChanged` listener but not with the `featureAdded` listener : For a new feature the `QgsFeatureId` is negative before a commit (-2 for example) and it seems that changeAttribute does not like that :

> Layer point: Feature -2 for attribute update not found.

How can I update a field automatically before a commit?

Here is my code :

```
#### variables ####
layerName = "point"
fieldName = "test"

## create layer object
layer = (QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName))[0]

## function updateField
def updateField(QgsFeatureId):
    field = layer.fieldNameIndex(fieldName)
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({QgsFeatureId:{field:"updateTest"}})
    
## listeners
layer.geometryChanged.connect(updateField)
layer.featureAdded.connect(updateField)
```

I work with QGIS 2.14.4

Comment: By the way, unless you definitely need to implement this by yourself in a script, you could use the AutoFields plugin, which handles automatic vector field updates for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tested your plugin, it works well but the attributes are not updated until you commit your edit change.

Comment: Right, they're not saved until you save. That something we could adjust for a next version. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://gis4programmers.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/working-properly-with-pyqgqis-edit-buffer-to-enable-undo-commands/) about listening to `featureAdded` in a safe way.

In your case, this should work:

```
layerName = "point1"
fieldName = "test"
addedFeatures = []

layer = (QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName))[0]
field = layer.fieldNameIndex(fieldName) 

def storeFeaturesIds(featId):
    addedFeatures.append(featId)

def updateAttributesAfterAdding():
    while addedFeatures:
        featureId = addedFeatures.pop()
        layer.beginEditCommand('Updating test field')
        layer.changeAttributeValue(featureId, field, "updateTest")
    layer.endEditCommand()

layer.featureAdded.connect(storeFeaturesIds)
layer.editCommandEnded.connect(updateAttributesAfterAdding)
```