# Change value of most recent added feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, editing

My code is iterating a shapefile and for each iteration a new point feature is added in another shapefile. Inside the same iteration I want to change the attribute value of the point feature which has just been added. I found this code [PyQGIS: using changeAttributeValues on new feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248317/pyqgis-using-changeattributevalues-on-new-feature) and tried to adapt it to my needs but I does not work. I get no error but also not the result needed. Where am I going wrong?

```
lawis_Pts = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('REL_LAWIS_profiles')[0]
ftsPoly = newlayer.getFeatures()

addedFeatures = []
def storeFeaturesIds(featId):
    addedFeatures.append(featId)
        

def updateAttributesAfterAdding():
    while addedFeatures:
        featureId = addedFeatures.pop()
        layer.beginEditCommand(layer.startEditing())
        layer.changeAttributeValue(featureId, field, new_val) #REL_LAWIS_ID is variable for new value
        layer.endEditCommand()

for feat in ftsPoly:
    #doing a lot of things with ftsPoly to get coordinates for my points..    
    lawis_Pts.startEditing()
    lawisfeat = QgsFeature()
    lawisfeat.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(lawisprofile_long,lawisprofile_lat)))
    lawisprovider.addFeatures([lawisfeat])
    lawis_Pts.commitChanges()

    #get field_id and new value
    field = lawis_Pts.fields().lookupField('REL_ID')
    new_val = REL_LAWIS_ID

    #run function
    lawis_Pts.featureAdded.connect(storeFeaturesIds)
    lawis_Pts.editCommandEnded.connect(updateAttributesAfterAdding)
```

Comment: Try with minimal code, is it working then? No for loop, functions. ..

Comment: I put the functions out of the loop now, also the list with featID. Still doesn't change values. I think the problem is with the first function. It does not append the ID of the feat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that does the job for me.

```
for feat in ftsPoly:
    #doing a lot of things with ftsPoly to get coordinates for my points..    
    lawis_Pts.startEditing()
    lawisfeat = QgsFeature()
    lawisfeat.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(lawisprofile_long,lawisprofile_lat)))
    lawisprovider.addFeatures([lawisfeat])
    lawis_Pts.commitChanges()

    #does the job:
    featnr = lawis_Pts.featureCount() #count feat of points layer
    featlist = list(range(featnr))    #write list with number of points
    wanted_feat = [featlist[-1]]      #get index of last idem in list
    lawis_Pts.select(wanted_feat)     #select last pointfeat of layer
    selection = lawis_Pts.selectedFeatures() #get feature
    
    #change attribute
    lawis_Pts.startEditing() #start edit session
    for lfeat in selection:  
        lawis_Pts.changeAttributeValue(lfeat.id(), rel_id_idx, REL_LAWIS_ID)
        lawis_Pts.changeAttributeValue(lfeat.id(), name_idx, LAWIS_NAME)
        lawis_Pts.changeAttributeValue(lfeat.id(), id_idx, LAWIS_id)
        lawis_Pts.changeAttributeValue(lfeat.id(), pdf_idx, LAWIS_PDFlink)
    lawis_Pts.commitChanges()
        
    lawis_Pts.removeSelection() #don't forget to remove, otherwise it adds to selection
'''
```